# Editar aparência dos meios de pagamento no Magento

Tags: php, magento, zend

Gostaria de editar a forma como os meios de pagamento aparecem no checkout do Magento, inserindo uma imagem com as bandeiras que cada sistema de pagamento aceita, mas não estou conseguindo.

[image: Meios de pagamento]

Qual .phtml eu devo editar?

Comment: Onde está a dificuldade, você encontrou o css ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe uma maneira muito fácil de fazer isso e funciona muito bem se você quer ter suas imagens antes do nome do método de pagamento:

Veja se você tem um arquivo chamado `app/design/frontend/seu-tema/seu-tema/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml`

Se existe este arquivo, faça uma cópia de segurança do mesmo. 
Se ele não existir, copie este arquivo em `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml` para a mesma pasta em seu tema, como citei antes (se não existir, crie `checkout/onepage/payment/`).

Abra (a sua cópia do) `methods.phtml` no editor e localize a seguinte linha:

```
<label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?> <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>
```

Aqui foi linha 54.

Altere para:

```
<label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/'.$_code.'.jpg') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?>" /> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?> <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>
```

Insira a imagem no skin do tema, para o método de pagamento Itaú Shopline da Gamuza (que eu uso), o código é `itaushopline_standard`, então a imagem chamada é `itaushopline_standard.jpg`.

Caso queira remover o nome do pagamento e ter só a imagem, a maneira mais fácil é não renomear o pagamento no backend. ;)